# react router Location "//playerOne" did not match any routes

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I'm trying currently trying to follow a react tutorial. I got stuck in a portion where I kept receiving a route does not match error.

Is there something wrong with my code or is this technique obsolete? Here is my framework version:

```
"babel-preset-es2015": "^6.16.0",
"react": "^15.3.2",
"react-dom": "^15.3.2",
"react-router": "^2.8.1"
```

Here is my code for the router:

```
var React = require('react');
var ReactRouter = require('react-router');
var Router = ReactRouter.Router;
var Route = ReactRouter.Route;
var hashHistory = ReactRouter.hashHistory;
var IndexRoute = ReactRouter.IndexRoute;
var Main = require('../components/Main');
var Home = require('../components/Home');
var PromptContainer = require('../containers/PromptContainer');

var routes = (
    <Router history={hashHistory}>
        <Route path='/' component={Main}>
            <IndexRoute component={Home} />
            <Route path='/playerOne' component={PromptContainer} />
            <Route path='/playerTwo/:playerOne' component={PromptContainer} />                        
        </Route>        
    </Router>
);

module.exports = routes;
```

Here is my PromptContainer:

```
var React = require('react');

var PromptContainer = React.createClass({
    render: function () {
        return (
            <div className="jumbotron col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3 text-center">
                <h1>SOME HEADER TEXT</h1>
                <div className="col-sm-12">
                    <form>
                        <div className="form-group">
                            <input className="form-control"
                            placeholder="Github username"
                            type="text" />
                        </div>
                        <div className="form-group col-sm-4 col-sm-offset-4">
                            <button className="btn btn-block btn-success"
                                type="submit">
                                Continue
                            </button>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div> 
            </div>
        );
    }
});

module.exports = PromptContainer;
```

Comment: why 2 splash in your question ? `react router Location “//playerOne” did not match any routes`

Comment: @MyMasterPeice That's the error I get when I browse to this url

http://localhost:8080/#/?_k=xxxx/playerOne

Comment: are you sure u r refering `PromptContainer` correctly ?

Comment: @MyMasterPeice Just added PromptContainer code above.

Comment: yeah i mean is `../containers/PromptContainer` correct in ur project structure?

Comment: also try replacing code as ` <Route path='/playerOne/' component={PromptContainer} />`

Comment: @MyMasterPeice yes it's correct in my project structure, 

tried adding the additional / , but didn't work :(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/125332/discussion-between-mymasterpeice-and-corbee).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note : there is hash history included in you url hence the below is how you redirect to routes manually

Lets assume base url is :

> http://localhost:8080/#/?_k=5mjzzn

Then you would redirect to PlayerOne as :

> http://localhost:8080/#/playerOne/?_k=5mjzzn

Note : if you use below url :

> http://localhost:8080/#/?_k=5mjzzn/playerOne

it would work since has history is include and hence warning is loged in console

Warning: [react-router] Location "//playerOne" did not match any routes

Comment: Cool, redirecting manually using the first url works! 
However it puzzles me that the video tuts used the second url for manual routes and worked for him.

Comment: Maybe he uses an older version?

Comment: @Corbee can you please ping me the referance of the video , i would like to point out how extract he appended the route at end of url and explain in detail

Comment: Sorry, just saw your comment, here is the link 
http://courses.reactjsprogram.com/courses/reactjsfundamentals/lectures/760395
it's in 3:33

Comment: but issue is sloved now !

Comment: @MyMasterPiece Sorry, I misunderstood.